# not redirecting to handler page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My java script which i had given in aspx page. the info should be redirect to handler page is not working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var Name;
  var Age;
 var Mobile;
 var Email;
 var Center;
 function getdata()
  {
   alert('Adding'); 
   Name=document.getElementById("txtname").value;
   alert(Name);
   Age=document.getElementById("Txtage").value;
   alert(Age);
   Mobile=document.getElementById("Txtmobile").value;
   alert(Mobile);
   Email=document.getElementById("TxtEmail").value;
   alert(Email);
   Center=document.getElementById("Ddlcenter").value;
   alert(Center);
   sendinfo();
  }
```

below query only not redirected to handler page

```
function sendinfo()
{ 
    $(document).ready(function(sendinfo){
    var url='Handler/Appoinment.ashx?Name='+Name+'&Age='+Age+'&Mobile='+Mobile+'&Email='+Email+'&Center='+Center+'';
    alert(url);
    $.getJSON(url,function(json)
    {
        $.each(json,function(i,weed)
        {
        });
  });
```

});

Comment: Your sendinfo function is missing a closing curly bracket.

Comment: i had changed that one .. but still its not going to handler page...